# Replace jQuery slide effect with CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replace my jQuery (UI) slide effect with a CSS3 transition effect as it looks smoother on handheld devices.

I'm sliding out an element to the left or right depending on the swipe event, altering its' contents and then sliding it in again from the opposite side.

**Old JS**

```
    var handleSwipeEvents = function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#myId').on('swipeleft', swipeHandler);
            $('#myId').on('swiperight', swipeHandler);
            function swipeHandler(event) {
                function slideEffect(swipeLeft, duration) {
                    var slideOutOptions = {"direction" : swipeLeft ? "left": "right", "mode" : "hide"};
                    $('#myId').effect("slide", slideOutOptions, duration, function() { // slide out old data
                        var slideInOptions = {"direction" : swipeLeft ? "right" : "left", "mode" : "show"};
                        $('#myId').effect("slide", slideInOptions, duration); // slide in new data
                        // Alter contents of element
                    });
                }
                var swipeLeft = (event.type === "swipeleft");
                slideEffect(swipeLeft, 300);
            }
        });
    };
```

I've only gotten half way with CSS and new JS. This is what I have:

**CSS**

```
#myId {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
}

.slide_left {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3D(-480px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(-480px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3D(-480px, 0, 0);
}

.slide_right {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3D(480px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(480px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3D(480px, 0, 0);
}
```

**New JS**

```
    var handleSwipeEvents = function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#myId').on('swipeleft', swipeHandler);
            $('#myId').on('swiperight', swipeHandler);
            function swipeHandler(event) {
                var swipeLeft = (event.type === "swipeleft");
                function slideOut() {
                    $('#myId').addClass(swipeLeft ? 'slide_left' : 'slide_right');
                }

                function slideIn() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#myId').removeClass('slide_left slide_right');
                    }, 300);
                }

                slideOut(); // It should teleport after the animation is done
                // Alter contents here?
                slideIn();
            }
        });
    };
```

It animates nicely, but after it's moved out of the view port I want the element to "teleport" to the opposite side before I change its' contents and then move it in to the center again. Giving it a nice slideshow effect.

How do I do that?

Also, I feel like I'm hacking here, how do I make the code prettier than it is now?

Am I going at this all wrong, if so what's the better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a working solution. I'm not sure if this is a "good" way to do it, but it works. I'm also not sure if it's better than my jQuery solution. It feels like a hack, so I'm going to continue to use my jQuery solution. But for future reference I'll leave this answer here.

**CSS**

```
#myId{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.outside_left {
    left: -960px;
}

.outside_right {
    left: 960px;
}

.slide_out_left {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(-480px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3D(-480px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3D(-480px, 0, 0);
}

.slide_out_right {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(480px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3D(480px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3D(480px, 0, 0);
}

.slide_in_left {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(-960px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3D(-960px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3D(-960px, 0, 0);
}

.slide_in_right {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(960px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3D(960px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3D(960px, 0, 0);
}
```

**JS**

```
var handleSwipeEvents = function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#myId').on('swipeleft', swipeHandler);
        $('#myId').on('swiperight', swipeHandler);

        function swipeHandler(event) {
            var swipeLeft = (event.type === "swipeleft");
            var duration = 300; // Each CSS animation requires <duration> ms before it's done

            $('#myId').addClass("animate");
            $('#myId').addClass(swipeLeft ? 'slide_out_left' : 'slide_out_right'); // slide out

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#myId').removeClass("animate slide_out_left slide_out_right");
                $('#myId').addClass(swipeLeft ? "outside_right" : "outside_left"); // "Teleport" to opposite side
                updateDate(swipeLeft ? getNextDate(currentDate) : getPreviousDate(currentDate));
            }, duration);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#myId').addClass("animate");
                $('#myId').addClass(swipeLeft ? "slide_in_left" : "slide_in_right"); // slide in
            }, 1.05 * duration);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#myId').removeClass("animate slide_in_left slide_in_right outside_left outside_right");
            }, 2 * duration);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Consider use the standard CSS below the verdor prefixed. If some browser use to have the prefixed version and now uses the standard the prefixed will be keeped.